# formating datetime into different datetime is not as easy as it seems

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have  `MeasureDate` column that has `datetime` as: `2013/10/03 12:36:01.265`

So,      I
want:   `2013-05-31 14:06:01.58`

and, I
have:  `2013/10/03 12:36:01.265`

It's 121 format that I want, I think....

I tried using convert() but it doesn't convert anything.

I tried every example on the internet, but nothing seems to be working.

I will keep trying but does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(22), GETDATE(), 121)
```

**Result**

```
2013-11-15 21:31:17.72
```

**Your Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE  (Col1 Datetime)
INSERT INTO @t (Col1) 
VALUES ('2013/09/28 13:14:38.81'), 
      ('2013/09/28 13:15:11.93'), 
      ('2013/09/28 13:16:29.78'), 
      ('2013/09/28 13:17:36.82')

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(22), Col1, 121)
FROM @t
```

**Result Set**

```
2013-09-28 13:14:38.81
2013-09-28 13:15:11.93
2013-09-28 13:16:29.78
2013-09-28 13:17:36.82
```

Comment: It doesn't convert it . My output:  2013/09/28 14:35:58.1

Comment: I have just shown you the results of your own data hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
select replace(convert(varchar, MeasureDate, 121), '/', '-')
 from Domain.dbo.datatable
```

Comment: you are using VARCHAR you need to use VARCHAR(22) as I have shown in my answer then you dont need to use the replace function at all